# Building Apache Pig for Hadoop 2.4 version

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I downloaded PIG 0.14 and did an **ant -dhadoopversion=23 jar** , but when I used it on Hadoop 2.4 its not working. Is there anything I should do other than just running ant?

Pig is running, but showing errors

ang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected

thanks !

Comment: it seems o.14 is not compatible with hadoop 2.4 , with 0.13 version of pig 2.4 is compatible..

Comment: The default Hadoop2 version is 2.4 in the latest trunk (0.14.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you checked out Pig from SVN trunk you can verify the Hadoop version it uses at 
`$PIG_HOME/ivy/libraries.properties` . For the "23" profile it is `2.4.0` .
After you have built Pig from source ( `ant -Dhadoopversion=23` ) you can verify whether ivy has retrieved the correct Hadoop jars under `$PIG_HOME/build/ivy/lib/Pig` .

I suspect that you have a wrong Hadoop version in your `PIG_CLASSPATH`.

Comment: This is the properties in $PIG_HOME/ivy/libraries.properties.  

    hadoop-core.version=1.0.4
    hadoop-test.version=1.0.4
    hadoop-common.version=2.4.0
    hadoop-hdfs.version=2.4.0
    hadoop-mapreduce.version=2.4.0

When I check $PIG_HOME/build/ivy/lib/Pig , I am seeing
hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar
hadoop-test-1.0.4.jar