# Error While generating pig-eclipse files (Building Apache Pig from Source)

Tags: apache-pig

ran the following commands successfully.

```
git clone -b spark https://github.com/apache/pig
ant -Dhadoopversion=23
```

However it gives me an error while generating eclipse files

```
ant clean eclipse-files
```

Error Stack Below

```
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-common;1.0.4: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-client;1.0.4: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;1.0.4: not found
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve] 
[ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
```

Full Stack Trace link 
https://gist.github.com/krishnakalyan3/b1a5c024c81ac5d211d6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291415/building-apache-pig-for-hadoop-2-4-version?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Current trunk generates the Eclipse files. But now Eclipse has problems. I opened [PIG-4520](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4520) to discuss.