# Pig: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

**Installation details:**

Pig Version: `0.16`
Hadoop: `2.7.3`

`pig -h` gives me results as expected.

I have tried : `ant clean jar-all -Dhadoopversion=23` - but it didn't help.

My Hadoop installation folder is : /usr/local/bin/hadoop-2.7.3/
`bashrc` file:

```
export PIG_HOME="/usr/local/bin/pig/pig-0.16.0"
export PIG_CONF_DIR="$PIG_HOME/conf"
export PIG_CLASSPATH="/usr/local/bin/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop/"
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/bin/pig/lib/*:.
```

Program:

```
log = LOAD '/home/dhaval/Desktop/excite-small.log' AS (user:chararray, 
time:long, query:chararray);
grpd = GROUP log BY user; 
cntd = FOREACH grpd GENERATE group, COUNT(log); 
DUMP cntd;
```

Error:

```
2017-04-20 23:38:39,761 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-04-20 23:38:39,831 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: GROUP_BY
2017-04-20 23:38:39,897 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
2017-04-20 23:38:39,898 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2017-04-20 23:38:39,926 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, ConstantCalculator, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PredicatePushdownOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter]}
2017-04-20 23:38:39,995 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager - Selected heap (PS Old Gen) of size 699400192 to monitor. collectionUsageThreshold = 489580128, usageThreshold = 489580128
2017-04-20 23:38:40,063 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2017-04-20 23:38:40,078 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.CombinerOptimizerUtil - Choosing to move algebraic foreach to combiner
2017-04-20 23:38:40,107 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2017-04-20 23:38:40,107 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2017-04-20 23:38:40,139 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
2017-04-20 23:38:40,140 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2017-04-20 23:38:40,148 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2017-04-20 23:38:40,149 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2017-04-20 23:38:40,174 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl - falling back to default JobControl (not using hadoop 0.20 ?)
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: runnerState
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2070)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.<clinit>(PigJobControl.java:51)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.newJobControl(HadoopShims.java:109)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:314)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:196)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:308)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1474)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1459)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1118)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:1081)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:994)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:747)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:376)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:231)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:206)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:564)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:176)
2017-04-20 23:38:40,177 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2017-04-20 23:38:40,183 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent
2017-04-20 23:38:40,183 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2017-04-20 23:38:40,183 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.output.compress is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress
2017-04-20 23:38:40,184 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Reduce phase detected, estimating # of required reducers.
2017-04-20 23:38:40,185 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Using reducer estimator: org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator
2017-04-20 23:38:40,190 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator - BytesPerReducer=1000000000 maxReducers=999 totalInputFileSize=208348
2017-04-20 23:38:40,190 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting Parallelism to 1
2017-04-20 23:38:40,190 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
2017-04-20 23:38:40,201 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2017-04-20 23:38:40,207 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2017-04-20 23:38:40,207 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cacche
2017-04-20 23:38:40,207 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Distributed cache not supported or needed in local mode. Setting key [pig.schematuple.local.dir] with code temp directory: /tmp/1492745920207-0
2017-04-20 23:38:40,285 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2017-04-20 23:38:40,285 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address
2017-04-20 23:38:40,294 [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2017-04-20 23:38:40,302 [JobControl] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl - Error while trying to run jobs.
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:243)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
2017-04-20 23:38:40,302 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
2017-04-20 23:38:40,309 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2017-04-20 23:38:40,309 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job null has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2017-04-20 23:38:40,309 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2017-04-20 23:38:40,310 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Could not write to log file: /log/path :/log/path (No such file or directory)
2017-04-20 23:38:40,310 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Unexpected System Error Occured: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:243)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)

2017-04-20 23:38:40,311 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2017-04-20 23:38:40,313 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.5.1   0.16.0  dhaval  2017-04-20 23:38:40 2017-04-20 23:38:40 GROUP_BY

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
N/A cntd,grpd,log   GROUP_BY,COMBINER   Message: Unexpected System Error Occured: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:243)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
    file:/tmp/temp1942265384/tmp-1728388493,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/home/dhaval/Desktop/excite-small.log"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "file:/tmp/temp1942265384/tmp-1728388493"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
null


2017-04-20 23:38:40,314 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2017-04-20 23:38:40,317 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias cntd
2017-04-20 23:38:40,317 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - Could not write to log file: /log/path :/log/path (No such file or directory)
2017-04-20 23:38:40,317 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias cntd
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:1019)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:747)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:376)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:231)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:206)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:564)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:176)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:1011)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIG - Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873050/pig-found-interface-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-jobcontext-but-class-was-expe)

Comment: @WattsInABox, this is Pig 0.16 and your link 0.12 that is not compatible with Hadoop 2. It is not a duplicate.

Comment: Good catch. I suspect the solution is something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291415/building-apache-pig-for-hadoop-2-4-version. OP, did you solve this? If not, check the ivy/libraries.properties file for any hadoop 1.0 settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a compatibility issue between pig-0.16 and hadoop 2.x
You can refer the pig version compatible with Hadoop-2.7.3 here -

https://pig.apache.org/releases.html#19+June%2C+2017%3A+release+0.17.0+available

That means you should use Pig 0.17 only with hadoop versions starting from 2.7.3

I know its an old question, but someone facing the same issue can benefit from this.